# ifstream says it opened a file but the file doesnt open

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am using visual studio 2017

I am new to c++ and here I tried to open a txt file, and confirming that it was opened.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <String>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    string text;
    infile.open("C:\\Users\\gab_a\\source\\repos\\one\\testing.txt");
    if (!infile.is_open()) {
        cerr << "Specified file could not be found "; 
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
    cout << "Opened file ";
    infile >> text;
    cout << text;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

it says that it opened it, and it even read the text that was inside the file, but the actual file isn't opening, I even put the file in the same directory as the project. There are also no errors, so why isn't my file opening?

Comment: If the stream says the file is open, and you can read the contents, I have no idea what you mean by "the actual file isn't opening."  You're using an absolute path, it doesn't matter where the file is relative to your project, it needs to be where the absolute path points.

Comment: @RetiredNinja What I mean by the file actually opening, is that the txt file actually launches and a notepad process actually shows up, and that's what's not happening, yes I can read the contents but its on the stream. Unless I'm going about this the wrong way in terms of opening files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is reading the data from the file into a stream. This is not the same as executing a program to open the file. To do that is generally OS specific, but if you're on Windows you can use `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess`. I do suggest you brush up on your C++ a bit - no offense intended

Comment: Yea after running around the internet a little bit I realized what I was doing, and i found my solution which was system(); , felt stupid lol because i didn't really read into what ifstream actually does. and yea I only started learning C++ yesterday, so my C++ is really bad haha.

Comment: @cyclasebricklayer Yea don't worry, we all start out as beginners.  Just an FYI, if I recall correctly, system() is bad practice, but I honestly would **not** worry about that now especially since you're really only getting into this.